# Extract table name from more than one schema length in Data Factory Expression

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to extract table name from schema.table_name, I have more than one schema where length is unknown. e.g. Finance.Reporting or Setup.System. I want to extract Reporting and System from these string using Expression in Data Factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#split) function to split the string based on delimiter which returns the array and get the second value from the string.

Note: Array index starts from 0.

`@split('Finance.Reporting','.')[1]`

[image]